# Python Json parse error: Key Error - self.url = json['id_str']

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a JSON file but getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data2spreadsheet.py", line 151, in <module>
    parse(json.loads(line))
  File "data2spreadsheet.py", line 119, in parse
    tw.parse(tweet)
  File "data2spreadsheet.py", line 78, in parse
    self.url = d['id_str']
KeyError: 'id_str'
```

Weird thing is that I am unable to reproduce this error everytime I run the code. At times, the code runs perfectly fine and then suddenly it refuses to co-operate. I have verified the JSON parse function in my data2spreadsheet.py script and it works fine with single JSON object. Any idea on how should I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Sample JSON object:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Jul 20 13:17:26 +0000 2017","id":8880,"id_str":"8880250","text":"Hello there !"}
```

Comment: This seems like in some variant your json file have not 'id_str' key.

Comment: Some additional information is required. What is "d"?

Comment: 'id_str' in <my JSON object> returns true . I am reading the file line by line. 'd' has one line instance of the file having a JSON object

Comment: Can you show example of your code? And sample of json?

Comment: You can catch this exceprion by folowing code: `try: ... except KeyError: print(d)` in block try you have to write your code ` self.url = d['id_str']` and you will get line with error. After that you read json format. I think problem in it

Comment: Add the sample of python code please

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the dictionary does not have the key 'id_str'.
If this key is present in your json file it means the code missed it, or did not understood it.

Have you tried the module json to import your file instead of writting your own parser?

Here is the link to the documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html.

The code would be like :

```
import json

fp = open(filename, 'r')
js = json.load(fp)
fp.close()
```

Where the variable js is a dictionary containing your json file.

Comment: I am using json.loads() method

Comment: can you give a sample json?

Comment: I've added sample object in the question description section

Comment: The problem must be coming from something else can we have detail on your code? (loops, multi-threading, several programs acessing the file, ...)